# Using GetSystemMetrics how to determine if a screen is touchscreen

Tags: java, lotusscript, touchscreen, getsystemmetrics

I read somewhere that using GetSystemMetrics, one can determine if a screen is touchscreen or not. I have a handle to this function in Java and Lotus Script. However, I am not sure what to do with it, and how to determine if the screen is touchscreen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GetSystemMetrics with the (SM_DIGITIZER) index should return non zero if there is a touchscreen.